# Apache Solr 6.6 replace document instead of update

Tags: python, solr, lucene, pysolr

I have configured solr 6.6.1 for a testing setup. After indexing few documents, I have to update few fields. I am using python client of [solr](https://pythonhosted.org/solrpy/reference.html). To update, following is my code snippet

```
import solr

def update_solr_index(_id, _value):
    print solr_conn2.add( id = _id, group2 = _value)

core_ulr = "http://localhost:8983/solr/use"
solr_conn2 = solr.SolrConnection(core_ulr)
update_solr_index(doc_id, field_value)
```

After execution (and commit), all other fields are removed from all documents and only two fields left that are doc_id and group2. What is the problem is this API or in my code?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in the API. You are asking solr to add a document with an ID field that is already present in your collection. The following actions happen in solr.

- Remove the existing document which has the same ID
- Add new document with only the fields specified in that API call

The solution you are looking for is a **partial update** of a document.

Refer to the reference link to understand more on this [Atomic updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-AtomicUpdates)

You need to send a map object for the field you want to update in your document.

```
solr_conn2.add(id=_id, group2=*****)
```

The value to group2 must be a map like this {'set':'value...'}

You can probably refer to this similar stackoverflow solution [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42097254/2591220)

Comment: It's important to mention that to use atomic updates, all fields has to be set to stored, or for certain field types, at least has to have docValues enabled.

Comment: You are right. The atomic updates link covers this point too.